# JavaScript - get value from dynamic key/value into dynamic key/value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var data = {
    "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_A":{
        "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1":{
            "key_1":"value_1",
            "key_2":"value_2",
            "key_3":"value_3"
        },
        "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_2":{
            "key_1":"value_1",
            "key_2":"value_2",
            "key_3":"value_3"
        },
        "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_3":{
            "key_1":"value_1",
            "key_2":"value_2",
            "key_3":"value_3"
        }
    },
    "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_B":{
        "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1":{
            "key_1":"value_1",
            "key_2":"value_2",
            "key_3":"value_3"
        },
        "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_2":{
            "key_1":"value_1",
            "key_2":"value_2",
            "key_3":"value_3"
        },
        "DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_3":{
            "key_1":"value_1",
            "key_2":"value_2",
            "key_3":"value_3"
        }
    }
}

alert(data[DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_A[DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1].key_1]);

alert(data[DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_A][DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1]["key_1"]);
```

I tried several solutions, but it did not !

Could someone explain me how to proceed ? Thanks :)

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What does "get value from dynamic key/value into dynamic key/value" mean? Can you provide us with an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 1):

There are special symbols(`/`) in `key`s of `data` object. This is the reason your code is not working.

To get value from this object, the `key` must be used as subscript.

```
alert(data["DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_A"]["DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1"].key_1);
```

OR for key_1 you can also use subscript `[]` notation.

```
alert(data["DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_A"]["DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1"]["key_1"]);
```

Check in docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
alert(data['DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_A']['DYNAMIC_KEY/VALUE_1']['key_1']);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pc4dnqz7/)